# List of all azure resource types in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

Is there anywhere you can get a full list of all the resource types offered by Azure? I'm doing policy/role management and there doesn't seem to be a great place to look for all resource types. Currently I've been using the `Get-AzureRmProviderOperation` but this still doesn't show everything. For example, there's no option for `Microsoft.Botservice`

Comment: If you just want to list resource types, you can use `Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ListAvailable | Select-Object ProviderNamespace, RegistrationState`.

Comment: Check out [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-services-resource-providers#match-resource-provider-to-service). @WayneYang The new cmdlet is `Get-AzResourceProvider` as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourceprovider?view=azps-9.4.0)  or AZ CLI : `az provider list`.

Answer (score 7):

Flagging the entire list is also available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/azure-services-resource-providers) for the resource providers and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations) for the types and actions

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Providers - List API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/providers/list) along with the `$expand=resourceTypes/aliases` query a parameter to give you everything that you need.

You can get all the resource types by
1. Appending `namespace` and `resourceTypes[*].resourceType` within each provider returned
2. The name of each alias is a resource type name already

Here is a simple nodejs script to get all the resource types sorted into a file

```
const fs = require('fs');

var a = <resource-provider-api-response-as-json-object>;

let final = [];

var b = a.value.forEach(p => {
  let ns = p.namespace;

  let rsts = p.resourceTypes.map(rst => ns + '/' + rst.resourceType);
  final = final.concat(rsts);

  p.resourceTypes.forEach(rst => {
    let aliases = rst.aliases.map(a => a.name)

    final = final.concat(aliases);
  });
});

final.sort();

fs.writeFile("random.data", final.join('\n'), function(err) {
  if(err) {
      return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Also, if you using `bash` with `az` and `jq` installed, you could simply run this :)

```
az provider list --expand resourceTypes/aliases | jq '[ .[].namespace + "/" + .[].resourceTypes[].resourceType , .[].resourceTypes[].aliases[]?.name ] | unique | sort' | less
```

You could just pipe the output to a file too for your use in other scripts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you want to see the template references then you can go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/. Note that as of this date, some resource types are missing (e.g. 'SendGrid.Email/accounts')

Answer (score 0):

Example using “az provider list”

```
$OutFileName = "resourcetypes.txt"
$output = @()   

$azproviders = az provider list | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($provider in $azproviders) { 
  foreach ($type in $provider.resourceTypes) 
  { 
    $output += $provider.namespace + "/" + $type.resourceType 
  } 
}
$output | Out-File $OutFileName
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).